# corss domain issue in getting cljs repl working

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get the cljs repl working. However I get the following error in chrome's js console-

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://0.0.0.0:3000/ from frame with URL http://localhost:9000/repl? ....... Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

I am serving the app in the clj repl using `(ring.util.serve/serve app)`. This opens up a browser on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

How do I resolve the cross domain issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In this context `0.0.0.0` is a special address that when passed to a socket bind implies that you want to listen on *all* addresses present on the machine.

To fix your problem you should be ok if you open the browser using the URL `http://localhost:3000` then the javascript and the frame hosting it will be in the same domain